# Configure log4j when using Weld CDI

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I'd like to programmatically adjust my logging file locations. Thus I want to overwrite the default values in my `log4j.properties` file. This is not opposing any problems I am using `LogManager.resetConfiguration()` and `PropertyConfigurator.configure(props)` so that my file locations are updated (stored in props). This methodology works, logging files are from this point onward written to a new file location.

My problem occurs when using Weld. This is due the fact that Weld internally is using a logger as well, stated in my logging-file: `2014-08-13 12:55:15.589 [main:0] DEBUG Weld.java:84 Method: <clinit> - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider`.

Since I'm using `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain` as main class, I do not have any influence on the logging capabilities of Weld. I now end up with 3 logging files (as described in my log4j.properties) on 2 different locations. Whereas one contains some Weld debug information and the other contains all the logging information from initialization and onward.

Thus logically I'd like to end up with only 1 directory with logging files, thus that Weld adjusts to the new log4j file location. Or to have log4j to copy the old logging contents, create new logging files + with old content and to delete the old logging files.

I do not want to use VM arguments, since I need to programmatically assign the logging locations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in cases like this is to use slf4j. See [bridging legacy apis](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Once you bridged all logging, you can use slf4j-to-log4j to direct all logging to your log4j settings.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I managed to load slf4j and slf4j-log4j12 and set the logging provider of weld to org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider. But still, weld is logging before I'm able to set my logging directories. Thus I still end up with 2 logging files (altho all logging after weld initialized is written to the new logging file). Any clue(s)?

Comment: Could you show me some code? Where do you init your loggers?